# how to create a map with value as templatized function pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, maps, function-pointers, shared-ptr

Below code doesn't compile, please help me where I'm missing. I have member functions with different return types and I need to call those functions by just passing a string name. So I have created a map, Below is the example which matches my requirement, but I'm not able to compile.

```
template<typename T1>
shared_ptr<T1> GetBasicClassInfo()
{
    T1 obj;
    shared_ptr<T1> pobj( new T1);
    return pobj;
}

class BasicClass
{
  public:
     std::string GetValue()
     {
         return "Successfull";
     }
     int GetInt()
     {
         return 5;
     }
};

template<typename T>
std::map<std::string, std::function<T()>> GetPropertyValue ={
   {"int",&GetBasicClassInfo<BasicClass>()->GetInt},
   {"string",&GetBasicClassInfo<BasicClass>()->GetValue}
};

int main()
{
   cout<<GetPropertyValue["int"]()<<endl;
   cout<<GetPropertyValue["string"]();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like XY problem.

Comment: Actual problem is I have a vector of shared pointer objects and User calls a property and I need to implement an interface which takes that property and returns value by calling a member function of a class.

Comment: You cannot get a different return type, depending on the runtime value. Types must be known at compile time. Therefore, you can either consider all cases using branching, or or specify the types explicitly as a template argument.  I find it difficult to understand what exactly are you trying to achieve

Comment: Well, [this](https://rextester.com/QDQ57979) makes your example work, though I doubt it's quite what you had in mind (like @DmytroDadyka, I'm not really sure exactly what you had in mind).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik As I understand it, the author wants to have an API that returns a different type depending on the string variable (or maybe constant) value.  In your example, you cast all types to a string, which probably loses original meaning.